# How should I box integer types in C++?

Tags: c++, integer, class-design, idioms

Suppose my code has

```
using foo = int32_t;
```

somewhere, and

```
using bar = int32_t;
```

then, for some reason, I need to distinguish between this type and other `int32_t`s (and their aliases). But - I still want them to behave just like `int32_t`s.

Now, I can write:

```
struct foo { int32_t value; }
struct bar { int32_t value; }
```

which distinguishes between the types. But - these structs don't behave like  `int`s at all; I can't even compare `foo`s to each others! (Well, not before C++20 anyway)

Since `int32_t` is not a class, I *can't* do:

```
struct foo : public int32_t { }
```

although that would give me exactly what I need.

So it seems what I want to achieve is a "boxing" (a-la Java, C# etc.) of plain integers into classes, and the rest will be taken care of by inheritance.

It's certainly possible to blurt out a lot of boilerplate and implement all of the relevant operators for integers: assignment, comparison, arithmetic, etc. But, you know, [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)!

If I could [override operator dot](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0416r1.pdf), that could save me all the code, but that proposal is stuck and doesn't look like it'll go somewhere soon.

So is there something else I could leverage to avoid all of that boilerplate?

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem to me.

Comment: You cannot distinguish the `foo` and `bar` aliases.

Comment: When you say you can't compare them, do you mean you want to compare a `foo` to a `bar`? That seems to go against you wanting to distinguish between them a bit. Or do you just mean `foo` to `foo` and `bar` to `bar`?

Comment: What you're talking about is a totally foreign concept in C++. I'm not sure it's possible.

Comment: Is this something like what you're trying to do? https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/doc/html/boost_units.html

Comment: I think the most important question to (possibly) answer this is *why* you need to distinguish `foo` and `bar`. What do they represent? Why they are different, but can still be compared to each other and to other ints? What does `foo * 5` mean?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Type safety. It is very easy to accidentally sent the wrong `int` to a function that accepts any old `int`. But if you could have an `int` that could never be confused with another, the compiler would catch such mistakes at compile time.

Comment: @Kevin: No, I didn't mean `foo` to `bar`; sorry, I phrased that sentence poorly. See edit.

Comment: @Kevin: I need them to be template parameters with different specializations.

Comment: @MarkRansom I'm not sure. I suppose I should be able to define a "foo dimension" and a "bar dimension". However, I don't want to be able to multiply foo's by bar's.

Comment: https://www.boost.org/libs/serialization/doc/strong_typedef.html

Answer (score 2):

There is one way I have tried (but not heavily tested) to avoid repeating the boilerplate. It uses templates to easily make a new type simply by supplying a different number as a template parameter. The resulting type can be type aliased to get rid of the ugly template definition:

```
namespace alt {

template<std::size_t TypeId, typename Number>
class typed_number
{
public:
    explicit typed_number(Number n): n(n) {}
    typed_number(typed_number const& tn): n(tn.n) {}

    typed_number& operator= (typed_number const& tn) { this->n  = tn.n; return *this; }
    typed_number& operator+=(typed_number const& tn) { this->n += tn.n; return *this; }
    typed_number& operator-=(typed_number const& tn) { this->n -= tn.n; return *this; }
    typed_number& operator*=(typed_number const& tn) { this->n *= tn.n; return *this; }
    typed_number& operator/=(typed_number const& tn) { this->n /= tn.n; return *this; }

    explicit operator Number() const { return n; }

    bool operator==(typed_number tn) const { return this->n == tn; }
    bool operator!=(typed_number tn) const { return this->n != tn; }
    bool operator<=(typed_number tn) const { return this->n <= tn; }
    bool operator>=(typed_number tn) const { return this->n >= tn; }
    bool operator< (typed_number tn) const { return this->n <  tn; }
    bool operator> (typed_number tn) const { return this->n >  tn; }

    typed_number operator+(typed_number const& tn) const { return typed_number(this->n + tn.n); }
    typed_number operator-(typed_number const& tn) const { return typed_number(this->n - tn.n); }
    typed_number operator*(typed_number const& tn) const { return typed_number(this->n * tn.n); }
    typed_number operator/(typed_number const& tn) const { return typed_number(this->n / tn.n); }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, typed_number<TypeId, Number> n)
        { return os << n.n; }

    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, typed_number<TypeId, Number>& n)
        { return is >> n.n; }

private:
    Number n;
};

}  // namespace alt

// give each incompatible type a different index
using dollars = alt::typed_number<0, int>;
using cents = alt::typed_number<1, int>;

int main()
{
    auto d1 = dollars(5);
    auto d2 = dollars(9);

    auto d3 = d1 + d2;

    std::cout << d1 << " + " << d2 << " = " << d3 << '\n';
}
```

You create the boilerplate **once** as a *template class* and *instantiate* it as different **types** merely by supplying a *unique* index as the first template parameter.

Comment: I meant avoiding even this. I'm sure there has to be some standard library or boost code which does basically the same thing.

Comment: instead of number one shall pass another class 
template<typename Tag, typename Number>
class typed_number...

class dollars_tag{};
class cents_tag{};
using dollars = alt::typed_number<dollars_tag, int>;
using cents = alt::typed_number<cents_tag, int>;

Comment: @PavloMur My code that I copied this from does exactly as you suggest. However I thought this was simpler and conveyed the basic concept.

Comment: @einpoklum This only has to be done **once**. All your other types can be created as template instantiations with no boilerplate at all.

Answer (score 0):

### Strong typedefs

Several on-and-off-site comments (including @HenriMenke) have brought up the term "strong typedef"s. C++ typedefs are "weak" - they define indistinguishable aliases. A strong typedef of a new type T as type U would make T behave like U, while not having type U.

What you want to do is define two "strong typedefs" of `foo` and of `bar` as int's.

There are at least two common strong-typedef, uh, libraries I guess you could say:

- Foonathan's [`type_safe`](https://github.com/foonathan/type_safe) ([repo on GitHub](https://www.boost.org/libs/serialization/doc/strong_typedef.html)): Provides `ts::integer<T>`
- Boost's [`strong typdef`](https://www.boost.org/libs/serialization/doc/strong_typedef.html), which is older and macro-based